# How to use GNU Parallel to run a list of command in a file?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I would like to use GNU Parallel to run N commands on P cores.  I put each command in a file: ListOfCommand.  Each line in that file corresponds to a different command and each line is the complete command that can be run 'as is' at the command-line.  There are many more commands than cores.  So I would like GNU Parallel to run only P commands at a time, and then whenever a command finishes running, the next command in the file should begin (dynamic scheduling).

It seems like this should be doable with GNU Parallel, but I'm having a hard time digesting the man page.  Does anyone know how to do this?

[EDIT] After more digging, this seems to work:

parallel -P 4 '{}' < ListOfCommands

Comment: Does this help: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards supplying the list of commands, you should be able to use any of the following equivalently:

```
parallel -j4 < ListOfCommands
parallel -j4 -a ListOfCommands
parallel -j4 :::: ListOfCommands
```

---

As regards what is run for each command in the list, you can use `{}` to identify parameters, but if you specify no command to be run, the line from your file is taken as the command:

So, if you make your `ListOfCommands` like this:

```
echo A
echo B
echo C
```

You can run the following and the command to run for each job is the `echo X` line from your commands:

```
parallel -j4 :::: ListOfCommands
A
B
C
```

If you just want to put the parameters for the command to run in a file, you write `ListOfParameters` like this:

```
A
B
C
```

then put the `echo` command on the **GNU Parallel** command line itself as follows and use `{}`:

```
parallel -j4 echo {} :::: ListOfParameters
A
B
C
```